# Waking a Windows (Spooler) printer

Tags: c#, .net, printing, windows-xp

I have a .NET 3.5 / C# application running on XP which receives data from another application in small batches (3 or 4 lines at a time), collects the data into a single print job, and eventually submits it to the Windows spooler.  This data collection phase usually takes 20 - 30 seconds.

When watching the system in operation, I noticed that the printer that's being used (a networked laser printer) takes a long time - a couple of minutes - to warm up, and obviously this warm-up phase starts only *after* I've sent the complete print command to the spooler.

So, this got me thinking - is there a generic "fire and forget" method I can use to tell the printer to start its warm-up sequence?  If so, I could trigger that immediately upon receiving the first chunk of data, and the printer can be warming up while I'm doing my data collection.

It's not the end of the world if this isn't possible, by any means, but it looks like a nice easy speedup!

Comment: How about issuing a print order, and then canceling it right away? This should make the printer start the warm up sequence, but once it's done, the job has been canceled. I guess it depends on the printers way of handling jobs.

Comment: I'm a bit concerned that if I do that and the printer's already powered-on, I might sometimes get the print.  Good idea though!  The more I look at the spooler API, the more I think this isn't possible.

Comment: Have you ever found out if this is at all possible. Have the same requirement, but don't think this is feasible.

Comment: I'm afraid not - but many of our sites are now using dot-matrix printers (I know, I know), so we're getting away with it most of the time!